# How to ignore dependsOn failure because some subprojects don't have the defined task

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, multi-project

I have a multi-project gradle build where not all of the subprojects have the same plugin, but I would like to define tasks in the root build.gradle file like this:

```
subprojects {
    task continuousBuild(dependsOn: ["clean", "check", "jacocoTestReport", "integrationTests"]
}
```

Not all subprojects have "jacocoTestReport" or "integrationTests" defined, but this task will fail because of that fact. How do I configure this to work, and frankly, why is the default behavior so strict?

Answer (score 0):

This is what ended up working for me:

```
   task continuousBuild(dependsOn: ['clean', 'check']) {
        def uncommonTasks = ['jacocoTestReport', 'integrationTests']
        dependsOn += tasks
                .findAll { uncommonTasks.contains(name) }
   }
```

And I forgot that I actually needed to run integrationTests in a doLast, which looks like this:

```
    task continuousBuild(dependsOn: ['clean', 'check']) {
        dependsOn += tasks
                .findAll { 'jacocoTestReport' == name) }

        if (tasks.findByName('integrationTests')) {
            doLast {
                integrationTests
            }
        }
    }
```